# Android layout into react native View

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, android-linearlayout, react-native-component

I creating an android native module from an existing Java library. This library, make a GLSurfaceView

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(new GLSurfaceView.Renderer() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
                   //Do things
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
                   //Do things
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
                {
                   //Do things
                }
            }
        });
```

into an android layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.___.FpvActivity">

    <com.____.GLSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.____.GLSurfaceView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and set it by 
        `setContentView(R.layout.activity_fpv);`

What I want to do, is a react native module ( only android ) to include this view into a React Native Component. This View must be in the background of other RN elements.
What I'd tried to do is to inflate this layout by a ViewManager by
        `View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_fpv, null);` but without solution.
    I can only see the original layout without my element ( put over in .js file)

Some ideas? This is my first experience with an RN Native module with layout interaction and I don't have much experience in Android/Java language